# Insert Query to run at 11:59 PM on every Sunday

Tags: php

I want to Insert data in a table, data of last week at 11:59 on every sunday

Comment: this automatization job is not best done in sql(query) or php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use sleep() for this, is a bad practice to keep a process active all the time for this. Use cron as is the right tool for the right job.

If you use linux than do this in a console as a root

```
crontab -e
```

This will allow you to edit the cron joblist. Add a line with

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
59 11 * * 0 /bin/php /path/to/your_script.php
```

Comment: the cron job should be `59 23 * * 0 /bin/php /path/to/your_script.php` the OP asked for 11:59 PM not AM

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it by cronjob (if it's a Linux server).

Learn more about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

Look at cronjobs, or let a PHP script run 24/7 and use time_sleep_until(float $timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

I like do to this kind of scheduling this way:

- create DB table called "scheduled", and insert to in all your scheduled jobs and their time.
- Create crontab job that runs every minute, pulls scheduled jobs from scheduled and run them.

easier to make changes -  manage, stop and start.

Comment: kinda inefficient to cron each minute for a weekly job, but a good idea  if you have a lot of various jobs

Comment: yea i know.. but i like the fact that you can make changes easily and in many ways, build a nice API and so on..